# How center using stacklayout and also depends of an image?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i want to center my image and label, and the label have to is center depending of my image, for example:

```
*****************************
*                           *
*        -----              *
*        - i  -'label'.     *  
*        -----              *
*                           *
*****************************
```

i have this code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Image Source=".image.png" WidthRequest="5">

                </Image>
                <Label Text="image"/>

        </StackLayout>
```

but i get so:

```
*****************************
*        ------'label'.     *
*        - i  -             *  
*        ------             *
*****************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `VerticalOptions`

```
<Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding DateFormat}"/>
```